# Ant War Task: how to specify several folders with class files and libs

Tags: java, ant

I have a Java webservice project. I want to build the War file using Ant War Task. As the project depends on sub projects (non web projects) there are several folders with class files and libs that have to been put in the War.
Is it possible to make the Ant War Task search more than one folder for class files? Same for libs.
Or do I have to copy all the class files in one folder first and give that folder to the Ant War Task?

Comment: What did you try? Are there any errors if you use multiple `lib` and `classes` sub elements?

Comment: I wasn't aware that I can use multiple classes and lib elements. I tried it and it works. Thank You!